# using async/await for sql data insert

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

```
function Recursive_scan_and_Insert (path_dir) { //scanning path_dir recursively and insert filepath into temporary list
    Recursive_Scan(path_dir, (err, files) => { //it's from npm recursive_readdir
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send('server error');
        }

        files.forEach(elements => {
            let params = [elements]; //
            DB("GET", "INSERT INTO filelist_t VALUES (null, ?, NOW(), 0, 0)", params).then(function(res) {
                console.log('data input');
            });
        });
    });
};

function Add_to_DB () { //moving temporal list to main list without duplicate
    DB("GET", "INSERT INTO filelist (id, path, addeddate, isdeleted, ismodified) SELECT NULL, filelist_t.path, filelist_t.addeddate, filelist_t.isdeleted, filelist_t.ismodified FROM filelist_t LEFT JOIN filelist ON filelist.path = filelist_t.path WHERE filelist.id IS NULL; DELETE FROM filelist_t; ").then(function(res) {
        console.log('data moving');
    });
};


app.get('/db', (req, res) => { //PROBLEM PART

    async function async_Two_Functions () {
        var object_path = '/want/to/scan/path';
        await Recursive_scan_and_Insert(object_path).then( () => {
            return Add_to_DB()
        })
    }
    async_Two_Functions();
    res.send(res);
});

app.get('/dbp', (req, res) => { //show main list to my web
    DB("GET", "SELECT * FROM filelist").then(function(res2) {
        res.send(res2.row);
    });
});
```

here's the thing.

there are 4 stage in my dream algorithm.

1. recursively scan all the path.
2. insert each data into temporary table.
3. moving temporal data on main table, without duplicate
4. present main table

it's very important to things get order. but I don't understand about `async` `await` exactly...

Comment: You can find a very good overview [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).  How it works is described in detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model).

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Which part of your code do you need help with?

Comment: @jfriend00 oh, my mistake. clearly said, `app.get('/db', ....` is not working asyncronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's a cleaned up version of the code with lots of changes.

```
const {promisify} = require('util');
const Recursive_ScanP = promisify(Recursive_Scan);

function Recursive_scan_and_Insert(path_dir) { //scanning path_dir recursively and insert filepath into temporary list
    return Recursive_ScanP(path_dir).then(files => {
        return Promise.all(files.map(elements => {
            let params = [elements];
            return DB("GET", "INSERT INTO filelist_t VALUES (null, ?, NOW(), 0, 0)", params).then(function(res) {
                console.log('data input');
                // what should the return value be here?
            });
        }));
    });
};

function Add_to_DB () { //moving temporal list to main list without duplicate
    return DB("GET", "INSERT INTO filelist (id, path, addeddate, isdeleted, ismodified) SELECT NULL, filelist_t.path, filelist_t.addeddate, filelist_t.isdeleted, filelist_t.ismodified FROM filelist_t LEFT JOIN filelist ON filelist.path = filelist_t.path WHERE filelist.id IS NULL; DELETE FROM filelist_t; ").then(function(res) {
        console.log('data moving');
        return res;
    });
};


app.get('/db', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let object_path = '/want/to/scan/path';
        await Recursive_scan_and_Insert(object_path);
        await Add_to_DB();
        res.send(somethingHere);        // you fill in what response you want to send here
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    }
});

app.get('/dbp', (req, res) => { //show main list to my web
    DB("GET", "SELECT * FROM filelist").then(function(res2) {
        res.send(res2.row);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send("Server Error");
    });
});
```

Changes:

1. Return a promise from every function that has an asynchronous operation in it
2. Return whatever you want the resolved value to be for the promise from every `.then()` handler
3. Promisify anything that uses a regular callback so you can do all control flow with promises
4. Use `Promise.all()` to know when multiple promises are done and to collect results in order from doing a set of asynchronous operation in parallel
5. Use `async/await` as desired, but particularly when you want to sequence multiple asynchronous operatoins
6. Use `try/catch` around any `await` to catch rejected promise that aren't being returned to a higher level where they will be caught
7. Use `.catch()` with any `.then()` that isn't being returned to a higher level where it will be caught

Open Questions:

1. Don't know what response you want to send from `app.get('/db', ...)`.  You will have to fill that in.
2. Are you expecting any resolved value from `Recursive_scan_and_Insert()`?
3. Does `Add_to_DB()` really accept no input?  It just reorganizes things already in the database?

Comment: very thanks for your detailed answer. I want to answer your questions here.

3. `Add_to_DB` seems so long, but it's just role as "send query" function. so actually, it's not necessary. but I don't know how to asyncronously "sending query" with other functions. so I wrapped up.

2. `Recursive_scan_and_Insert()` has no return. because it's exists for a button.